# Доступ к VM Azure извне

Tags: linux, веб-программирование, centos, azure

Поднял на Axure сервер CentOs. В тренировочных целях установил ligthtpd.
Запустил его. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Через портал открыл порт 80 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В самой машине порт открыт 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
но дефолтная страничка не открывается.
Что я сделал не так?

Comment: вероятно, вы обращаетесь по протоколу ipv4. а программа, судя по приведённой картинке (кстати, текстовую информацию лучше предоставлять в виде текста, а не картинки: и читать удобнее, и поисковики её проиндексируют), слушает только ipv6.

Answer (score 1):

Пропишите в настройка LightHttpd следующие настройки:

```
# listen to ipv4
server.bind = "0.0.0.0" 
server.port = "80" 

# listen to ipv6
$SERVER["socket"] == "[::]:80" {  }
```